# How do I derive a class from struct dirent and use it to store result from readdir()?

Tags: c++, unix, filesystems, dirent.h

So I derived a class from struct dirent. This is what my derived class header looks like:
    #ifndef Direntry_hpp
    #define Direntry_hpp

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Direntry : public dirent{
private:
public:
     void print(ostream&);
     char* name(){ return d_name; }
     ino_t inode(){ return d_ino; }
     unsigned int type(){ return d_type; }
};

#endif /* Direntry_hpp */
```

So In my code I try to use readdir() and my a class object of the above class to store it. So readdir() returns struct dirent*. I have tried everything but I can't use my class object to store the results of readdir().

```
for(;;){
    //I want to say Direntry *dirEntry but it doesn't work when I try to store the result of readdir().
    struct dirent* dirEntry; 
    if((dirEntry = readdir(dir)) == nullptr) break;
    if(params.vFlag && dirEntry->d_type != DT_REG){
        cout << setw(12) << dirEntry->d_ino << left << dirEntry->d_name << endl;
    } else if(dirEntry->d_type == DT_REG){
       cout << setw(12) << dirEntry->d_ino << left << dirEntry->d_name << endl;
       Stats stat; //This class is derived from stat in the <sys/stat.h> library and it works.
       if(lstat(path, &stat)) fatal("lstat error");
    }
}
```

So that Stat class is derived from  and it works but for some reason struct dirent doesn't work the way I anticipate it to. What did I do wrong or am I trying to do something that should not be done?

**Edit:**

```
Direntry* dirEntry;
if((dirEntry = readdir(dir)) == nullptr) break;
```

The code above produces a error at compile time that says:
 
Assigning to 'Direntry *' from incompatible type 'struct dirent *'

Comment: "some reason struct dirent doesn't work the way I anticipate it to" --> How did it fail - show output?  What was expected?

Comment: Hope this code is for studying only and will not be used somewhere else...

Comment: Yes this is purely for studying of the UNIX file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DIR* dir = opendir(path);    

for(;;){
    Direntry* dirEntry;
    if((dirEntry = (Direntry*)readdir(dir)) == nullptr) break;
    ...
}
```

So I found out that you can cast the return value of readdir() from struct dirent* to Direntry* which is the class that derives from struct dirent

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works as long as your own Directory object does not contain its own member variables or have any virtual methods.